# Why personal emails from my website is going to Gmail Spam box?

Tags: gmail, postfix-mta, spam, spam-prevention, spamassassin

In case you think this is a duplicate, trust me, it's not.

Problem: All personal emails (not newsletter or mass email) sent from my website domain like john@mysite.com is going to Gmail Spambox (and Outlook.com too). Even simple email like "Hi, how are you doing?" with little content and a signature get marked as spam. Tested with two new email addresses. Domain is 1 year old and the site is not even launched yet!

My Email Server Settings:

- SPF: Pass
- DKIM: Pass (2048 bits key length)
- DMARC: Pass
- Blacklist: No for IP and domain (Checked on
  multitude on sites)
- rDNS: Done and pass
- Google Postmaster Tools: It
  keeps saying "No data to display at this time. Please come back
  later."

Anything else I should try? I'm running Postfix with SpamAssassin at AWS.

Comment: How is this a SpamAssassin or spam-prevention question? You have a deliverability problem, not a spam-receiving problem. Anti-spam systems penalize young domains by the way (as this is a hallmark of [hailstorm spam](https://blog.talosintelligence.com/2016/12/in-eye-of-hailstorm.html "Disclaimer: this is my team's work")).

Comment: Delivery services like Mailgun have a generous free tier (10,000 emails per month before you get charged I think) so there is no reason to send emails from your own server in 2020